# Format output in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I store a few notification for user in html format in model. ex

$not = "**Test** Notification";

But as per inputs I've got from other, I need to escape the output, using h() function. So
my question is, is it safe (against XSS) in this case to output without escaping as data is generated internally rather than getting input from end user.

Similarly, at other places, I output this kind of stuff using AJAX and calling .html() in jQuery. is it safe in this case also?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal text strings you can answer that question yourself:
Is is absolutely impossible to put any char like `<` or `>` etc in that string from the frontend or backend? If so, YES. If not, you need to wrap it with h().
It is not just XSS, also the layout can break with invalid handling of the output data.

So if you are generating that string in the PHP code, you usually know how "safe" that method is (as the outside then has limited access).

Also note, that when allowing HTML via wysiysg editors, the above does not apply, as HTML cannot be h()ed. Thus you need to sanitize the data upon input using sth like https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-html-purifier

Comment: Thanks Mark for your Inputs! I've used ckeditor at some other places.. In this case I'm using html purifier before saving data. And outputting (in edit action) with desired class => ckeditor, but in cakeway!